# Jasmine OR Expect

Tags: testing, jasmine

I am trying to implement something in this case where

```
expect(Object.keys(testObj)).not.toContain(value)
 OR expect(testObj).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
    value: "1"
    }))
```

Pretty much I am trying to check for the scenario when the obj does not have a key OR if it does have that key, that key equals to a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Answer**

You could do something like this.

```
function assertKeyDoesntExistOrHasSpecificValue(myObj, key, expectedValue) {
  if(!myObj.hasOwnProperty(key) || myObj[key] === expectedValue) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}

it('should not have property x OR property x should have the value y', () => {
    expect(assertKeyDoesntExistOrHasSpecificValue(myObject, 'myProperty', 'myValue')).toBe(true);
});
```

In the above I have created a function with does the leg-work of the check and call that within a single jasmine expect. Therefore, I can just check that the helper function returns true based on the input given.

**Further on isolated test**

However, it sounds like you are attempting to test a conditional in your logic with a single test case. I would advise against this as test cases should be predictable.

i.e. either it has the property or it does not.

I would suggest writing multiple test cases where in test case 1 the input yields an object without the key. And test case 2 where the input yields the object with the expected key and value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This doesn't directly answer the question and as such should be a Comment instead of an Answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended to include a direct answer.

Comment: Hey Duncan, that was what I did originally. Just wondering if there was a better way.